# How do I calculate the sum of all numbers from 0 to n?

Tags: java, loops, sum

So I'm trying to calculate all the numbers from 0 to a given number (n) with a loop as seen in my code but I just can't seem to manage how.

```
public static int sumOfNumbers(int... params) {

     int sum = 0;

     for (int i : params) {
         sum = i;
     };

     return sum;
}
```

Comment: You need to *add* to `sum`, not assign to it

Comment: try this `sum+= i;`

Answer (score 13):

You're overwriting `sum`, not adding to it. You should use the `+=` operator instead of the `=` operator:

```
sum += i;
```

Alternatively, you can treat this as a mathematical problem, and use the formula for the [sum of an arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum):

```
public static int sumZeroToN(int n) {
    return n * (n + 1) / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the sum of numbers in a series, so you can do this in O(1) using:

```
int sum = n * (n + 1) / 2;
```

Where `n` is the highest number in `params`, `params` being an array/collection of numbers from `0` to `n`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) from `IntStream`:

```
return Arrays.stream(params).sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to calculate an arithmetic series sum so you can just do this without a loop:

sum=((param+1)*param)/2;

param is the given number.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the var sum each loop, and forgetting to sum, you need alter your code to something like this:

```
public static int sumOfNumbers(int... params) {

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i : params) {
        sum += i; //Same as sum = sum + 1;
    };

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want from 0 to n you could use `IntStream` e.g.

`IntStream.rangeClosed(0, n).sum()`

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
 sum = sum + i;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop, not for each loop! For each loop use with a List.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
   sum += i // same as sum = sum + i;
}
return sum;
```

Or simply use:

```
int sum = n * (n + 1) / 2;
```