# How to use a loop to write a function that adds 1 through n

Tags: java, loops

I have to come up with a code that returns 0 if the int input n is less than 2, and returns the sum of integers 1 through n if n is greater than 1.
EX: If n is 4, the return would be 1+2+3+4

Here's the code I have so far, for some reason it always returns more than it should be when I run it:

```
    public static int sumton(int n){
        if (n<2){
            return 0;
        }
        int result=0;
        int i=1;
        while (i<=n){
            i=i+1;
            result=result+i;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        return result;
}
```

Comment: move `i = 1 + 1` until after `result = result + i`. It might also be clearer to use '+=' for `i += 1` and `result += i`

Comment: Returns what, _exactly_, for what inputs? What does your debug output tell you?

Comment: By the way, sum from 1 to n is the same as 0 to n. Why do you need to check less than 2? An input of 1 should really return 1

Comment: Also, you can do this without any loop in constant time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362031/how-do-i-calculate-the-sum-of-all-numbers-from-0-to-n

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop instead of while loop.

```
 public static int sumton(int n){
    if (n<2){
        return 0;
    }
    int result=0;
    
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
      result = result+i;
      System.out.println(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In While loop, it should be like :

```
  while (i<=n){
        result=result+i;
         i=i+1; //i++
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```